# C++ TStringsList parse explanation

Tags: c++, c++builder, ini, tstringlist, tinifile

I'm trying to read a ini file in a value listbox.
Example below works, but i don't know why.

`ReadSectionValues` contains a string list of ini lines.
How does Rad Studio parse the lines with:

`ListValues->Names[i]` is first part of the line and `ListValues->Values[ListValues->Names[i]]` is the second part?

```
int i;
try

{

    //ShowMessage( ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex] );

    TStringList *ListValues = new TStringList;

    TIniFile* SettingsFile = new TIniFile(ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName) + "settings.ini");

    String s;

    s = ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex];

    SettingsFile->ReadSectionValues( s , ListValues);

    for (i = 0; i < (ListValues->Count); i++) {

        //ShowMessage(ListValues->Names[i]);

        //ShowMessage(ListValues->Values[ListValues->Names[i]]);

        vList1->InsertRow(ListValues->Names[i] , ListValues->Values[ListValues->Names[i]],True);

    }

    delete SettingsFile;

    delete ListValues;

}

catch(Exception* e)
{
    ShowMessage(e->Message);
}
```

Please explain, Rad stuido help found no explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void __fastcall ReadSectionValues(
  const System::UnicodeString Section, 
  System::Classes::TStrings* Strings
)
```

is a method, which gets all lines of ini-file section with name `Section` and stores them in TStrings-object `Strings`. Note that these strings have format `name=value`.

TStrings class has two access properties [Names](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStrings_Names.html) and [Values](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStrings_Values.html). Their parse algorithm is very simple. If you get `stringsObject->Values[1]` it takes second line from `stringsObject` and splits it into two strings on `=` (or other value of `NameValueSeparator` property of `stringsObject`). The string to the left of `=` (separator) is returned as name (by property `Name`) and the string to the right of `=` is returned as value (by property `Value`).

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean that i can use the Tstring for use in splitting a string in sections using the delimiter? I ask this because searching for a split string function gave me some complex results and using Tstrings would solve that to then.

Comment: Yes, you can. I did it and it worked for me. The only limitation (compared to good split function) is that you can split only in two parts and on single character only, but not on substring.

Comment: Please, do not forget to tick-select the right answer. It will give you +2 [reputation points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) too :)

Comment: Ok cool, i forgot about that. Went straight on with the program :)